# What is the e.which value for command key on mac keyboard?

Tags: jquery, keyboard

i want to know the e.which value for command in mac.i believe windows window key and mac command are same.they have same signal code.

For windows window key e.which is 91,92 you can check it [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).
For Mac command key i don't know could somebody tell me. Is both have the same code in event.which?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Safari, Chrome and Opera**

The left `CMD`-keys returns **91** and the right one **93**.

**Firefox**

Both `CMD`-keys return **224**

**Edit**

As requested in the comments here some more values. Those are the same across the browsers:

c = **67** / s = **83** / v = **86** / x = **88**

Comment: Interesting! Why is Firefox being rebellious? ;)

Comment: @insertusernamehere could you tell the code for c,s,v,x is those are same as in windows?

Comment: Thanks dude. +1 for you.now i have tried with virtual box too:)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell this by capturing a `keydown`, `keyup` or `keypress` event and then checking out all the properties of `e` by debugging in any of the major browsers.

here's a quick JSFiddle to write out the `e.which` values as they're pressed in the textbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/HYLXR/1/

Comment: Thanks i don't have mac now that is why i posted this question, So that person who have mac can test in the link and help me.if i know the code i'll do functions based on which key is pressed

Comment: Oh - I see. Well, @insertusernamehere has given you some numbers and browser variants of those numbers too, but you'll need to test them somehow ;)

Comment: hopefully if more answer refers the same code then i don't have to test i believe. If you have mac try the code.Thanks